# GetWindowPlacement behaving correctly in Debug but incorrectly in Release

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, desktop-bridge

I am trying to find out if a specific window is maximized. I do it with the help of a hWID. When I do it after compiling for debug, I get a messagebox saying "3" when the window is indeed maximized. However, if I compile for release, I get a messagebox saying "-1", whatever the state of the window is.

The following code is in a WPF project, that is packaged in an UWP package and launched as FullTrustProcess:

```
private unsafe void IsMaxed(IntPtr hWID)
{
WINDOWPLACEMENT plc = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
plc.length = (UIntPtr)sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
WINDOWPLACEMENT* pplc = &plc;
GetWindowPlacement(hWID, pplc);
MessageBox.Show(((int) plc.showCmd).ToString());
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static unsafe extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, WINDOWPLACEMENT* lpwndpl);
```

Comment: I don't know why this isn't working in release, but you shouldn't need to be writing unsafe code to call this. See [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowPlacement.html) for how to call it with safe code.

Comment: Does the full trust wpf project compile in release model?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yes, but thankfully using the pinvoke code has solved the issue.